# "не" - слитно или раздельно: "не()развлекательная задача"?

Tags: орфография

Но эта не развлекательная задача не привлекла
внимания ученого.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуем написать слитно: Но эта неразвлекательная задача не привлекла внимания ученого. Такое написание возможно, если существует слово "неразвлекательный". Однако в словаре его вряд ли можно найти, в текстах же в основном встречается раздельное написание НЕ в отрицательных конструкциях, например:

а) Это совсем не развлекательный жанр. Книга отнюдь не развлекательная, но читается легко, с интересом. (Это усиление отрицания).

б) Это, конечно, не развлекательное чтиво для летнего отдыха. «Вести недели» ― не развлекательная программа. (Здесь НЕ относится к словосочетанию, а не к слову).

Тем не менее слитное написание встречается, например: "Это другая реальность. Неразвлекательная".

Неразвлекательный - тот, который не служит для развлечения,то есть не является предметом удовольствия, веселия, забавы. Можно заменить синонимом  "серьезный".

Вывод

а) Лучше написать раздельно, сославшись на отсутствие слова "неразвлекательный" в словаре.

б) Можно написать слитно, сославшись на утвердительный характер синтаксической конструкции с заменой синонимом.

в) В целом всю конструкцию можно считать авторской (малоупотребительной), поэтому и оформление может быть авторским.

Comment: Спасибо большое.